# Custom keyboard layout problem High Sierra

Tags: macos, keyboard, high-sierra, bug, input-source

I have just upgraded my OS to **macOS High Sierra**.

I have been using a custom layout for my Magic Keyboard. But after upgrading to the newer version is stopped working.

I have installed the custom keyboard again using **Ukele**, but it doesn't work properly.

Here are some weird problems I have encountered

1. It shows the custom layout in top bar. However I am not able to select this layout. Also this layout is missed in the System Settings. [image]
   [image]
2. After rebooting, it may be able to switch to the custom layout and even work correctly, but after some time it may stop working, or there are a lot of duplicated layouts will be displayed in the Settings.
   [image]
3. When switching to another input source using Cmd-Space it may show an empty list item without any title.
   I need to add my custom layout every time I reboot my laptop.

Please suggest how to fix this problem, I cannot work with the default keyboard layout.

**UPDATE**

Something really weird is happening to new OS

Here is duplicated layouts, and as far as they are same, I can't remove duplicates.

[image]

Comment: In general, when you have a problem with a layout you made with Ukelele, it's good to ask their users group:   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ukelele-users

Comment: What is special about your custom keyboard?

Comment: @TomGewecke, nothing special about keyboard layout, just changed some keys and nothing more

Comment: I have a keyboard layout which matches the standard PC not mac layout (just because I touch type and had used it for years before getting a mac) and now it just shows up as greyed out and I cannot remember for the life of me where I got this layout from nor can i remember how to 'install' it. This was never previously a problem til I switched to high sierra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to try based on others who have had this kind of problem with other keyboards

- Make sure you do not have Siri turned on and that its keyboard shortcut is set to none.
- If your layout is in Home/Library, try Library instead.  And vice versa, and try it in both at same time.
- Disable any antivirus apps
- [Safe Boot](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25617)
- Set up new user account and see if it works when logged into that

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
After 3 months of suffering that problem, I finally solved it

There is a solution:

1. Create new user on your macOS
2. Go to Users/[username]/Library/Preferences (these folders is
   hidden by default in order to show them, press CMD + Shift + [>.])
3. Find **com.apple.HIToolbox.plist** and COPY it, save it in a place
   where you can access it later from your main account
4. Now, just switch to your main account, and replace that file in your
   main account with the one you copied from the new one, Restart the
   Mac

This method helps me, I have found solutions before that suggested deleting this file, but most likely macOS keeps the last backup of com.apple.HIToolbox.plist and when you delete it, it just restores the same file with error.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That sadly doesn't work (anymore)

Answer (score -1):

Ukelele is **BUGGY** software. I've had the problem you mention more than once, and the only answer was to forego the notion of creating an entire bundle and instead to create a layout only. You must be careful not to select the 'Name' option on the 'Keyboard' menu or the 'Rename' option on the 'File' menu. If you do, the keyboard will not install no matter what you do subsequently, up to and including loading and manually changing the content files.

Instead, just use the 'Install' option on the file menu, and it will install the keyboard using the filename you chose when you created the keyboard file.

Comment: I've never had any problems with dozens of layouts I've made that weren't caused by the OS or 3rd party software.  Have you taken your issues to the google user group?  Ukelele's author participates there and is normally very active in fixing bugs.